# Separability of a polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I have a non zero polynomial $f\in F[X]$ where $F$ is a field. Let $L$ be a field extension of $F$ so that $f$ splits completely in $L[X]$, so $f(X)=c\prod_{i=1}^n (X-a_i)$ with $c,a_i\in L$.

> If the roots $a_i$ of $f$ are all distinct then why is the same property true for any other field $L'$ over which $f$ splits completely?

I've tried looking for a proof in algebra books but I haven't been able to find one.

Any help (proof or a reference) will be much appreciated.

Comment: Consider the splitting field $K$ of $f$ over $F$. Then every field $L$ on which $f$ splits contains $K$.

Comment: So the roots $a_i$ are the same for any splitting field $L$?

Comment: That was very helpful. Many thanks. Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F$ be a field, and $f\in F[X]$ a polynomial.
The presence/absence of multiple roots for $f$ in any extension field can be decided without ever needing to exit the field $F$. This is because a univariate polynomial has multiple zeros, if and only if $\gcd(f,f')$ is non-trivial. This can be found in many algebra texts. A logical place is when separability is discussed, but it may come earlier. That greatest common divisor can be computed by Euclid's algorithm, and a glance at the algorithm tells us that the operations never produce coefficients $\notin F$. Therefore the algorithm runs the same way in any extension field of $F$.

Consequently if $f$ and $f'$ have no common zeros in some extension field of $F$, they won't have common zeros in any other extension field of $F$ either.